# How do you give a git commit a name?

Tags: git

How do you give a git commit a name?

E.g., from [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) Angular JS tutorial (click *Workspace Reset Instructions*):

```
git checkout -f step-2
```

How did they name the commit `step-2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wouldn't use [`git tag`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) alone, as it produces a **lightweight** tag (a tag reference for the SHA-1 object name of the commit object).

In the case of the [angular/angular-phonecat](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/), they use:

```
git tag -m "step-2 angular template with repeater" step2
```

Adding a comment is enough to make it an "**annotated**" tags; they contain a creation date, the tagger name and e-mail, a tagging message, and an optional GnuPG signature.

- **Annotated** tags are meant for release
- while **lightweight** tags are meant for private or temporary object labels.

As you can see, [**step2** is a release (annotated) tag](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/releases/tag/step-2).

Answer (score 8):

You can use a tag:

```
git tag step-2 *commit-id*
```

Comment: You may want to read [this](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#how-git-stores-references).

Comment: @MarkReed there's a lot of info there; what were you indicating specifically?

Comment: Good question.  A bit less than two years ago I might have remembered the answer. :) Sorry for the vague comment.

Comment: I found the section 'Naming branches, tags, and other references' in what @MarkReed pointed to quite illuminating